# problema con vim, como quitar caracteres especiales?

Tags: linux, vim

Como quito lo simbolos que aparecen al final e inicio de cada linea, soy principiante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: que editor es??? parece que tubieras activada una opcion que se llama mostrar todos los caracteres, que muestra infincluso los caracteres de *fin de Linea* o *Salto de Linea*

Comment: el editor es VIM, claro quizas pueda parecer ambiguo el error. Todo se resume en los caracteres que aparecen al incio y final de cada linea de texto, entoces necesito saber como ocultarlos, ya que se hace incmodo poder usar el editor de texto.

Answer (score 0):

Probá correr `:set nolist` en vim. list es un booleano que si está activado muestra los tabs como `CTRL-I` y muestra un $ luego de cada final de línea.

Si cada vez que iniciás vim está activada esta opción, probá revisar el archivo .vimrc y borrar la línea que dice `set list`